# Flex : forcing extension on a file name

Tags: apache-flex, file, download, forcing

In flex when I allow user to download a file using :

```
dwFile = new FileReference();
dwFile.download(downloadURL, dwFileName);
```

Is there a way to ensure that the downloaded file always ends up with the extension .tar or any other extension for that matter? By default I give it a name like xyz.tar,
but as of now the user can tamper with filename, including its extension. Can
I prevent him from doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not eliminate the ability to modify the extension and make it only the file name....

```
dwFile.download( downloadURL, StringUtil.substitute("{0}.tar", dwFileName) );
```

Comment: tried this. doesn't make any difference at all. In the download dialog box, filename is still shown as xyz.tar, and I can still tamper with the extension.

Comment: oooohhh I know what you mean now.... yea I don't think there is anything you can do about that.